# Update if tuple is in the set, else insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, exists, insert-update

I ran some query and got a set of tuples like ((A1,B1), (A2,B2), (A3,B3)....).
I need to check if a tuple from above set exists in a table XYZ(A,B,C). If it exists, then update C else insert (Ax,Bx,C) into the table.
I tried using the below query but it doesn't work. Is there any other way?

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * from XYZ as t where (t.A, t.B) in (select u.A, u.B from diff_table as u)) THEN 
THEN UPDATE XYZ as v SET C = 1 WHERE (v.A, v.B) = (t.A, t.B) ELSE
INSERT INTO XYZ (A,B,C) values (u.A, u.B, 1) END;
```

Comment: Take a look to [`INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: A and B combination can be non unique

Comment: If they can be non-unique, then you have a problem: How will you figure out which tuples will be updated and which won't be updated? Besides that, you'll always face the risk of inserting a duplicate entry. Consider adding a unique index to those fields and use `insert ... on duplicate key update`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it the other way round:

1. Update the ones that exist
2. Insert the ones that don't

Or if you have primary keys

1. Insert all with default value for C (existing will get rejected)
2. Update all

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you want is `insert . . . on duplicate key insert`.

First, you need an appropriate index (if you don't have one):

```
create index idx_xyz_a_b on xyz(a, b)
```

Then:

```
insert into xyz(a, b, c)
    select dt.a, dt.b, 1
    from diff_table dt
    on duplicate key update set c = 1;
```

By the way, if the value already exists, are you sure you want to set it to 1 instead of incrementing it?

```
insert into xyz(a, b, c)
    select dt.a, dt.b, 1
    from diff_table dt
    on duplicate key update set c = c + 1;
```